# Group by and conditional filter

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `tibble` which resembles the following:

```
data<-tibble(ref=c("ABC", "ABC", "XYZ", "XYZ", "FGH", "FGH", "FGH"), 
             type=c("A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B"))

  ref   type 
1 ABC   A    
2 ABC   B    
3 XYZ   A
4 XYZ   A    
5 FGH   A    
6 FGH   A    
7 FGH   B
```

I need to group by `ref` and if--within a group--`type` B is present, return that row, else default to return any row (but only 1 row) of `type` A.

Expected output:

```
  ref   type 
1 ABC   B      
2 XYZ   A    
3 FGH   B
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only have `A` and `B`, then you can arrange and simply get the first row, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
 group_by(ref) %>% 
 filter(type %in% c('A', 'B')) %>% #If other types exist
 arrange(desc(type)) %>% 
 slice(1L)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   ref [3]
  ref   type 
  <chr> <chr>
1 ABC   B    
2 FGH   B    
3 XYZ   A
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a more general solution if there could be more than two types?

Comment: Edited my answer. Have a look

Answer (score 2):

with large amounts of data, it is better to do sorting before grouping

**tidyverse**

```r
library(tidyverse)
df<-tibble(ref=c("ABC", "ABC", "XYZ", "XYZ", "FGH", "FGH", "FGH"), 
             type=c("A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B"))

distinct(df) %>% 
  arrange(ref, desc(type)) %>% 
  group_by(ref) %>% 
  slice_head(n = 1) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   ref   type 
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 ABC   B    
#> 2 FGH   B    
#> 3 XYZ   A
```

**data.table**

<sup>Created on 2022-04-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

```r
df<-data.frame(ref=c("ABC", "ABC", "XYZ", "XYZ", "FGH", "FGH", "FGH"), 
             type=c("A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B"))

library(data.table)
setDT(df)[order(ref, -type), .SD[1], by = ref]
#>    ref type
#> 1: ABC    B
#> 2: FGH    B
#> 3: XYZ    A
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This is pretty much the same as mine

Comment: yes, I added a note "with large amounts of data, it is better to sort before grouping" and there is a data.table solution

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a more general solution if there could be more than two types?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `which.max` over boolean to extract the desired rows

```
data %>%
    group_by(ref) %>%
    slice(which.max(type == "B")) %>%
    ungroup()
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  ref   type 
  <chr> <chr>
1 ABC   B
2 FGH   B
3 XYZ   A
```